# Codeception unit testing php. Check that a function has been called with a certain parameter

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, codeception

I try to find the solution for the simple issue. I need to check, that  a function has been called with a certain parameter. But I can just check, that  a function has been called and return some parameter. I was searching in codeseption docs very long. Have codeception some method for this?

```
   public function testSomething()
   {
      $conversation = $this->make('Class', [
         'ask' => \Codeception\Stub\Expected::once('this string will be returned')
      ]);
      $conversation->run();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I find an solution. It is PHPUnit syntax, but it works! We testing that method ask() was called with 2 params ('first param', 'second param') at firsttime. Maybe someone has a more elegant solution?

```
  public function testSomething()
   {
      $conversation = $this->make('Class', [
         'ask' => \Codeception\Stub\Expected::once()
      ]); 

  $conversation->expects($this->exactly(1))
     ->method('ask')
     ->with('first param', 'second param');

      $conversation->run();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

With codeception I'm using something like this :

```
$conversation = Stub::make(MyClass::class,
            [
                'ask' => Stub\Expected::exactly(1, function ($params)  {
                    $this->assertEquals('yourFirstParam', $params[0]);

                })
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it!